# Solaris 10 ssh auto logout

Tags: ssh, solaris

For some reason, I am getting automatically logged out of one of my shells on one Solaris box but not on the other one.  I don't seem to have any bash variables set to auto logout.  What else should I check?

Answer (score 1):

the auto logout is happening due to the IdleTimeout variable is set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

I believe if you have KeepAlive set in your .ssh/config then it should stop (I haven't tested this though, so ymmv).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you checked for the TMOUT variable in your bash session, correct?

Is there a firewall between your ssh client and the Solaris  server in question?  It might be dropping you after some amount of inactivity.  If so, you could modify the sshd_config on the server and add the KeepAlive and ClientAliveInterval settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Cisco devices in their default configuration can cause this.  Do you have  different Cisco devices between you and each server?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ServerAliveInterval 600` in /etc/ssh/ssh_config on your client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the /etc/default/login (TIMEOUT) and /etc/profile (TMOUT) files.

They have timeout settings for the login shell.